# Jasper Report Heading on new page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report that contains lists that I iterate over to display a title and then some contents. If the contents are too long the report spans more than 1 page. Depending on how much space this left on the overflow page the title is displayed on the overflow page or pushed to the following page. I always want it to be pushed to the following page. I have tried to use `elementGroup` and `group` to try and make sure that everything is keep together, but nothing seems to work. The report looks like this:

```
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.12.2.final using JasperReports Library version 6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_Latest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a3bcc82f-7412-423e-b109-7a84c111800f">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Localhost Mongo"/>
    <subDataset name="productDetails" uuid="e21ddc86-6be3-47de-8a73-e0f836ddd976">
        <field name="product" class="java.util.List">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[product]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="features" class="java.util.List">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[features]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="interviewQuestionDetails" uuid="143b235e-1410-4d07-a21c-2757f36193f2">
        <field name="questionText" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[questionText]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="responseText" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[responseText]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="fromDate" class="java.util.Date">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Date(0)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="formattedFromDate" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false" evaluationTime="Late">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[DATEFORMAT($P{fromDate}, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="toDate" class="java.util.Date">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Date()]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="formattedToDate" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false" evaluationTime="Late">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[DATEFORMAT($P{toDate}, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="instrument" class="java.util.List"/>
    <field name="instr" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="subjects" class="java.util.List"/>
    <field name="purchaser" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="orderReference" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="businessUnit" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="serviceCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="field1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="field2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="field3" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="questions" class="java.util.List"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="300" splitType="Prevent">
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="10" width="555" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="cc984ca4-2e56-47ec-aeae-ab8ae5445a37"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Object: " + $F{instr}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="530" height="40" uuid="06fc31b9-564a-4b0f-ae22-5283b68d950b"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="productDetails" uuid="c5fd0b5b-723e-4216-8f9a-7dac0c38d2e4">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource($F{subjects})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="40" width="530">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="500" height="20" uuid="d372c83e-bf42-4aa8-bbda-3841d5c069a6"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <font size="13" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[""+org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join($F{product}.toArray(),", ") + ""]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="500" height="20" uuid="4208d514-f41e-4b37-814d-06d797c3a088"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Features: "+org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join($F{features}.toArray(),", ") + ""]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="80" width="555" height="20" uuid="1c2e1d42-100d-4d1d-be01-9a089c1693ce"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Purchaser: " + $F{purchaser}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="100" width="555" height="20" uuid="1c0a0e9f-59e1-4754-b5cc-f6d469e8617d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Order Reference: " + $F{orderReference}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="120" width="555" height="20" uuid="1c0a0e9f-59e1-4754-b5cc-f6d469e8617d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Unit: " + $F{businessUnit}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="140" width="555" height="20" uuid="1c0a0e9f-59e1-4754-b5cc-f6d469e8617d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Code: " + $F{serviceCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="160" width="555" height="20" uuid="63032d3a-0cfe-441a-bb37-5a845b2e61c7"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Content:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="180" width="535" height="20" uuid="c2c03017-b519-4675-8dd0-22b1ef374aa7"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["invoice pricing structure Executive innovate Multi-lateral digital transmit South Africa Bedfordshire deposit orange Money Market Account Michigan Technician infomediaries Rand Loti Cotton salmon Frozen Arizona Tasty Rubber Keyboard Mauritius Practical Metal Chicken channels Dynamic. invoice pricing structure Executive innovate Multi-lateral digital transmit South Africa Bedfordshire deposit orange Money Market Account Michigan Technician infomediaries Rand Loti Cotton salmon Frozen Arizona Tasty Rubber Keyboard Mauritius Practical Metal Chicken channels Dynamic. invoice pricing structure Executive innovate Multi-lateral digital transmit South Africa Bedfordshire deposit orange Money Market Account Michigan Technician infomediaries Rand Loti Cotton salmon Frozen Arizona Tasty Rubber Keyboard Mauritius Practical Metal Chicken channels Dynamic"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="200" width="535" height="20" uuid="85d8213d-ea25-40c8-9d0c-07d289aaf716"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="220" width="535" height="20" uuid="d2d98193-506a-418e-a66f-756402c75825"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field3}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="240" width="555" height="20" uuid="63032d3a-0cfe-441a-bb37-5a845b2e61c7"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Interview Questions]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="260" width="530" height="40" uuid="06fc31b9-564a-4b0f-ae22-5283b68d950b"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="interviewQuestionDetails" uuid="a66a2c1a-bba0-4858-b3ed-ee25a9bd28a1">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource($F{questions})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="40" width="530">
                            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="0" width="500" height="20" uuid="4b6eccd1-2234-40c3-ac88-256f621b784d"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{questionText}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="20" width="500" height="20" uuid="d74141e1-fef5-4b7f-85af-ccd041fe1162"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{responseText}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

It's this section `<textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Object: " + $F{instr}]]></textFieldExpression>` that I also want to be displayed at the start of a new page. Can I use `isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true"` on the reportElement? I can't seem to get this to work or a group with `keepTogether="true"` or `isStartNewPage="true"`. Not sure what to use. Just want each `Object:`  value to be displayed at the start of a new page.

Comment: Can you share output?

Answer (score 0):

try using isIgnorePagination="true" property

or check Ignore Pagination in Report where you set Page Format and so...